# Data undefined in Async data return

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, axios

I've a problem with a return data from an async function located in Controller file.
I would to get my data in "let data", but it is undefined, I can't understand where is my error.. 
(of course in my concept of async functions :) )

Here my example:

```
// index.js
const DataController = require('../controllers/DataController');

router.get('/test', function (req, res, next) {

  let data = DataController.getData().then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp); // <-------- here is undefined

  });
});

// DataController.js
const axios = require('axios').default;
exports.getData = async function getData() {
        return axios.get("https://it.lipsum.com/")
            .then((response) => {
                // console.log(response)
                return response;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(function () {
                // always executed
            });
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `.then(function () { // always executed });` what is the code here?

Comment: Don't mix promises and async/await, use one or the other

Comment: @VLAZ an example of HTTP call from Axios documentation, the code was structured as a paste

Comment: and the moral of that story is don't just cut and paste code you don't understand....

Comment: This should simply be: `const response = await axios.get("https://it.lipsum.com/");`

Comment: @RogerAI well, that is the problem. If you have `promise.then().then()` the *second* `.then()` gets its value from the return of the previous `.then()`. So, if you have a `.then()` that doesn't return anything before yours, you get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the data from the `then` call.

```
// DataController.js
const axios = require('axios').default;
exports.getData = async function getData() {
        return axios.get("https://it.lipsum.com/")
            .then((response) => {
                // console.log(response)
                return response;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                // always executed
                return res;
            });
    }
```

The way it works that the Promise always returns the last value `.then` call returned, so your last `.then` call was returning then `undefined`.

Small note about `let data =`  because the call is `async` you will see `Promise` not the data the promise will resolve to. You can use `async/await` syntax in the following way.

```
router.get('/test', async function (req, res, next) {

  let data = await  DataController.getData();
});
```

Comment: There is no point in returning the same result twice

Comment: i was already tried this solution, but not working. I've used the @Liam const resp = axios.get(); and in first page .then( (resp) => console.log(resp) ); That work like a charm

Comment: Yep, there is no point. I just describe the problem with the current code, and why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your files like this:

**index.js**

```
// index.js
const { getData } = require('../controllers/DataController');

router.get('/test', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let data = await getData();
    console.log(data);
    return res.status(200).json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ', error);
    return res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      error
    });
  }
});
```

**DataController.js**

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

const getData = async () => {
  try {
    let response = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: "https://it.lipsum.com/"
    });
    return response
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
}

module.exports = { getData };
```